# tinemce sugarcrm not able to get field value

Tags: javascript, tinymce, sugarcrm

i have configured tinymce in sugarcrm by following docs

https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_12.0/Architecture/TinyMCE/

in record.php

```
 array (
                'readonly' => false,
                'name' => 'internal_notes',
                'studio' => 'visible',
                'rows' => 3,
                'span' => 12,
                  'type'          => 'htmleditable_tinymce',  
                  'span'          => 12,   
                  'tinyConfig'    => array(     
                  'script_url'                        => 'XXX/custom/epicom/tinymce/tinymce.min.js',     
                  'height'                            => '100%',     
                  'width'                             => '100%',     
                  'theme'                             => 'advanced',     
                  'skin'                              => 'sugar7',     
                  'plugins'                           => 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak   
                                                          spellchecker searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor',     
                  'entity_encoding'                   => 'raw',     
                  'forced_root_block'                 => false,     
                  'theme_advanced_buttons1'           => "code,separator,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,separator,forecolor,backcolor,separator,fontsizeselect",     
                  'theme_advanced_toolbar_location'   => "top",     
                  'theme_advanced_toolbar_align'      => "left",     
                  'theme_advanced_statusbar_location' => "none",     
                  'theme_advanced_resizing'           => false,     
                  'schema'                            => 'html5',     
                  'template_external_list_url'        => 'lists/template_list.js',     
                  'external_link_list_url'            => 'lists/link_list.js',     
                  'external_image_list_url'           => 'lists/image_list.js',     
                  'media_external_list_url'           => 'lists/media_list.js',     
                  'theme_advanced_path'               => false,     
                  'theme_advanced_source_editor_width'=> 500,     
                  'theme_advanced_source_editor_height'=> 400,     
                  'inlinepopups_skin'                 => 'sugar7modal',
                  'relative_urls'                     => false,     
                  'remove_script_host'                => false,   
                                  
                ),
              ),
```

I am able to generate html template in TextArea in record.js . but when I save records , I am not able to get new editied Data from TextArea Field... I get only Old Set HTML data

I used this code

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()
 tinymce.get("myTextarea").getContent()
```

but this code always have null value of activeEditor and getContent .

How do i Get value from HTML Editable TextArea Fields ??

Answer (score 0):

If you're in `record.js` controller code, you should be able to get the contents of the field like any other field. Like this:

```
let descHtml = this.model.get("description");
```

If this fails in an asynchronous method, make sure that `this` is correctly pointing to the record controller.
By either using `_.bind()` or a custom variable like `self` to "transfer" the controller's `this` to the async method.